# Sublime Text 3 Emmet plugin support JSX for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3, jsx, emmet

How to make sublime emmet plugin expand html abbreviation support JSX for `.tsx` file?

Sublime text 3 can good support `JSX` for `.jsx` file, but it seem not support for `.tsx` file. We can add a custom key binding to let emmet expand work at `.tsx`, but not all features, like the very useful feature instead `className` of `class`

example:

`p.test` will expand to `<p className="test"></p>` but not `<p class="test"></p>`